# Questionnaire data analysis

Tags: r, data-mining

I have a questionnaire for different years. The questionnaire layout is the same for every year. The questionnaire has Likert-scale *definitely agree* to *definitely disagree*. The questions are the in one column and the number of responses is corresponding with the liker scale, which is in each row from top to bottom.

```
|-------------| Category1| Q1 | q2 |  Category2| Q1 | q2 |  q3
|-------------| Average  |    |    |  Average
| agree       | 5        | 5  | 5  |      8    | 9  | 6  |  1
| disagree    | 4        | 2  | 2  |      3      4    3     3
```

This an example of the data.

Would I use the survey package? what benefits are there? Or should I use a normal association rule and have an association between the question? This is just an example to see any trends and patterns.

Comment: Let me verify that I get this correctly: all data belongs to one respondent and is ordered increasingly over time - newer responses appear on lower rows than older ones?